# VS debugger skips ctors in base class

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

It seems that Visual Studio debugger (I've checked VS 2015 and VS 2017) skips constructors and assignment operators in the base class. If I create a new C++ Win32 console application project with the following code

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
    B() { std::cout << "ctor"; }
};

struct S : B { };

int main()
{
    S s1;

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot step into B::B(), "ctor" is printed and the debugger goes to the "return 0;" line. In the disassembly the "call S::S (01713D4h)" is followed by a piece of code that is not attributed to any source ("Source not available"):

```
00E51DF0  push        ebp  
00E51DF1  mov         ebp,esp  
00E51DF3  sub         esp,0CCh  
00E51DF9  push        ebx  
00E51DFA  push        esi  
00E51DFB  push        edi  
00E51DFC  push        ecx  
00E51DFD  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
00E51E03  mov         ecx,33h  
00E51E08  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00E51E0D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
00E51E0F  pop         ecx  
00E51E10  mov         dword ptr [this],ecx  
00E51E13  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this]  
00E51E16  call        B::B (0E51389h)
```

How can I step into B::B() (without using a breakpoint)?

Comment: I got the Email warning from the develop community site, and you could also add your comment and discuss this issue there:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same issue as yours, not find the VS settings which could impact the debugger tool, so I help you report this issue to the product team here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/77978/vs-debugger-skips-ctors-in-base-class.html.

If possible, you could also add your comment and vote that report directly. If I got any update from the product team, I will share it here.